# can't see onReceivedError in webview

Tags: android

I have a problem in old hardware can't see this code

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                mywebsite.loadUrl("about:blank");
                pd_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dialog.show();
                Toasty.error(Home.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
            }
```

Full Codes

```
mywebsite = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywebsite);
        pd_loading = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pd_loading);
        CallWebView();


        mywebsite.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebsite.loadUrl(Information.URL_Home);

        mywebsite.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view ,String url)
            {
                pd_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mywebsite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                mywebsite.loadUrl("about:blank");
                pd_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dialog.show();
                Toasty.error(Home.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
            }




        });
```

when the network connection is lost the old devices can't see onReceivedError , but new devices have no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the method:

> onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
>   String failingUrl)

This method was used in API level 22-.

```
 mywebsite.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view ,String url)
            {
                pd_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mywebsite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                mywebsite.loadUrl("about:blank");
                pd_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dialog.show();
                Toasty.error(Home.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();
            }


           //For versions < Android M (API 23).
           @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                 mywebsite.loadUrl("about:blank");
                pd_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dialog.show();
                Toasty.error(Home.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,true).show();

            }


        });
```